# simplify array list in java / processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing

How can I simplify this long list.. I don't want to write Arduino.LOW so many times..

```
int[] values = { Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW,
 Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW,
 Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW, Arduino.LOW };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a for-loop to initialize your array, if you dont know the size use an `List<Integer>` instead of an `Array`.

```
int [] values = new int[14];

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    values[i] = Arduino.LOW;
```

Comment: The array length should probably be 14, as it's 14 values in OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. 
You can use

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
int [] values = new int[14];
Arrays.fill(values, Arduino.LOW);
```

But it is not exactly the same..

Comment: in the console of proceesing it says: unexpected token:(